# Copy labels to multiple variables from different variables

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working with a df with many versions of the same variables, so they need similar, but different labels. For example, bev_1 is "water category" and bev_1_amt is "water ounces" and. T original variables have a label already, all new transformations do not. With hundreds of variables, I would like to assign any variable name containing text e.g. "bev_1" to be assigned the label from the original bev_1 variable.

```
library(dplyr)
library(labelled)

bev.df<- data.frame(
  bev_1=c(5, 3, 2, 5, 4),
  bev_2=c(6, 4, 4, 5, 5),
  bev_1_amt=c(2, 2, 3, 3, 2),
  bev_2_amt=c(3, 4, 5, 5, 4)) %>%
  set_variable_labels(bev_1 = "water", bev_2= "juice")
```

I've tried many versions of the below code and just can't get it to run. Any help appreciated.

```
bev.df %>%
  set_variable_labels(select(., contains("bev_1"))= var_label(select(., bev_1)))
```

I would like any variable with name containing the text "bev_1" to have the same label as the variable bev_1.

Comment: I would probably try some form of pattern matching & manipulation on the column names directly (e.g. `gsub("bev_1", "water", colnames(bev.df))`), rather than run operations on data frame itself...

Comment: Thanks, this would change the variable name, but I am only wanting to change the variable label. For example, each variable name that contains "bev_1" would be assigned a label with "water".